# Verify links of a .chm file

Tags: chm

I have few chm Files.In those files I have a large number of links. Most of the links are within the file.
So is there any tool to verify that all those licks are working, none of them is a broken link.
As I don't want to manually click on each link to check its functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use [FAR HTML](http://www.helpwaregroup.com/products/far) (a commercial tool) to check links in CHMs among other things. It checks links within the CHM file, web links, links to anchors (*file.htm#anchor*), and image src paths. You can read more about FAR's link checker here:

http://helpware.net/FAR/help/dlg_examine.htm#Check_Links_Page

Comment: I agree with Helen that FAR as a "Swiss army knife" for help files is useful for the link checking too.